# A job interview study guide told me to build a hash with an array?

Tags: python

How can you build a dictionary with fast lookup and no collisions using only arrays in python?

I have >5 years of experience and have built functionality for millions of users spending 10's of millions of dollars, and do not understand at all where to start.

Comment: No collisions? And there's no constraint on the input?

Comment: well the simplest solution is 2 arrays one for keys and one for values

Comment: @DarkLeader well, that doesn't provide you fast look-up.

Comment: maybe build something like a binary tree which will be stored in an array but data stored will be nodes with two values **key** and **value** and few functions that will add and retrieve data

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well correct  me if i'm wrong but isn't the point of the hash table is to get some value and return an index? so will have another function to produce that value and store in the array at some index and return that index so you can use the index in the second array?

Comment: @DarkLeader yes, but if your keys are stored in a list then your lookup is linear time, which is definitely slow. It isn't clear what the OP's constraints are, but definitely it's probably looking for some form of hash table or tree-map.

Comment: well maybe it's about technicalities? since your interviewer said arrays instead of lists maybe they meant the array module? for all i know this is the same as an array in C (as opposed to a double linked list as in a python `list`), which should theoretically allow you to do it? https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: I would question what they mean by "no collisions". Most hash tables have collisions and ways to deal with them. So I would wonder if "no collisions" means *really* no collisions, or minimal collisions and deal with them appropriately. If you really need *no* collisions you either need infinite storage or some constraint on keys.

Comment: Hash table with no collision is possible if you have the keys known beforehand, then you can craft a *perfect hash function* for that. This remind me of the [`gpref`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) tool but it generates C code. IBM has a [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-gperf/) on how this can be used.

Comment: Right @adrtam -- that part of what I meant by `some constraint on keys`

Comment: Hello @Josef_the_third could you verify if my posted answer is close to what you need? Though I wasn't able to satisfy the requirement of "no collisions" due to the same reasons stated in the comments here. Would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps could be a good starting point. An implementation of a custom dictionary using only arrays. But this has a lot of limitations. Notable limitations are:

- Collisions might happen. As already raised in the comments, if we would want a dictionary with no collisions, I believe that there should be some form of constraint(s) in the keys that we could use as a property during hashing (in other words, during selection of a target bucket / array_location) to make sure no single key:value would live in the same bucket. Example of constraints could be that each key has a unique length, or each key starts with a different character, or each key has a different integer-sum when its contents (converted to ints) are added up, etc.
- The bucket / array size does not resize. Currently the size is 100. So if you store 101 items, then there would be a guarantee of at least 1 collision.
- The supported types for the key is currently limited to int and str.
- The hashing algorithm could be improved. Currently, it does nothing for int while for str, it just performs an xor per ASCII code of each character.

In general, the algorithm runs O(1) on average but still O(n) on worst case. Setting new keys just requires to get the target position in the array and places it there, while getting the values calculates that same target position and fetches the value in there.

**Code**

```
def my_hash(variable):
    """Currently, only types int and str are supported"""
    if isinstance(variable, int):
        return round(variable)
    elif isinstance(variable, str):
        if len(variable) == 0: return 0
        result = ord(variable[0])
        for index in range(1, len(variable)):
            result ^= ord(variable[index])
        return result
    return 0

class MyDict:
    def __init__(self):
        INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 100
        self.internal_array = [[] for _ in range(INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE)]

    def set(self, key, value):
        hash_value = my_hash(key)
        array_index = hash_value % len(self.internal_array)

        # In the case that the bucket at self.internal_array[array_index] is not empty and there is
        # a new key to be placed on it, then there is a collision. At this point, it would be O(n)
        # where n is the number of colliding keys. This could perhaps be improved into O(log n) if
        # we maintain each bucket as sorted, or even O(n) if we maintain a secondary hash table on
        # each bucket which of course requires a second hasher logic.
        for item in self.internal_array[array_index]:
            if item[0] == key:
                item[1] = value
                break
            print("WARNING: Collision detected for key", key)
        else:
             self.internal_array[array_index].append([key, value])   

    def get(self, key):
        hash_value = my_hash(key)
        array_index = hash_value % len(self.internal_array)

        # As noted above in set method, there is a collision if the self.internal_array[array_index]
        # bucket contains more than one key:value pair.
        for item in self.internal_array[array_index]:
            if item[0] == key:
                return item[1]
        return None

    def show(self):
        print("Showing buckets with contents:")
        for index, bucket in enumerate(self.internal_array):
            if len(bucket) == 0: continue
            for item in bucket:
                print("Bucket[", index, "] ==> key:", item[0], "value:", item[1])

        print("Showing all buckets:")
        print(self.internal_array)

obj = MyDict()

print("Setting keys...")
obj.set("GOAT", "Michael Jordan")
obj.set("humans", "The Wildlife Killers")
obj.set("py-2", "sorry, end of life")
obj.set("GOAT", "LeBron James")
obj.set(69, "an ordinary number")
obj.set("Linus", "Gates")
obj.set(12, "los meses en un ano")
obj.set("beaver", "the best animal out there!")

print("\nGetting keys...")
print("Linus is", obj.get("Linus"))
print("12 is", obj.get(12))
print("GOAT is", obj.get("GOAT")) # key with an updated value
print("69 is", obj.get(69))
print("humans is", obj.get("humans"))
print("beaver is", obj.get("beaver"))
print("py-2 is", obj.get("py-2"))
print("COVID is", obj.get("COVID")) # non-existent key

print("\nDisplaying everything...")
obj.show()
```

**Output**

```
Setting keys...
WARNING: Collision detected for key 12

Getting keys...
Linus is Gates
12 is los meses en un ano
GOAT is LeBron James
69 is an ordinary number
humans is The Wildlife Killers
beaver is the best animal out there!
py-2 is sorry, end of life
COVID is None

Displaying everything...
Showing buckets with contents:
Bucket[ 7 ] ==> key: beaver value: the best animal out there!
Bucket[ 12 ] ==> key: humans value: The Wildlife Killers
Bucket[ 12 ] ==> key: 12 value: los meses en un ano
Bucket[ 22 ] ==> key: py-2 value: sorry, end of life
Bucket[ 29 ] ==> key: GOAT value: LeBron James
Bucket[ 69 ] ==> key: 69 value: an ordinary number
Bucket[ 77 ] ==> key: Linus value: Gates
Showing all buckets:
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [['beaver', 'the best animal out there!']], [], [], [], [], [['humans', 'The Wildlife Killers'], [12, 'los meses en un ano']], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [['py-2', 'sorry, end of life']], [], [], [], [], [], [], [['GOAT', 'LeBron James']], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [[69, 'an ordinary number']], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [['Linus', 'Gates']], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```